# Link Buttons in ListView Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have Link Buttons(say 1 and 2) in List View.
There exists a Parent Update Panel.

Then we have a Child Update Panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updActivePol"runat="server"UpdateMode="Conditional"ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
```

In that we have a listView.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvPolicy" runat="Server">
//Then we have a Button.
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID = "imgClaims"  title="Check Claim Status"  height="17" width="16" runat = "server" CausesValidation = "false" OnClientClick="javascript:EnableClaims();"
                                        ImageUrl = "~/images/searchHoverButton-sel.png" OnClick="imgClaims_Click" CommandName = "Claims" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("PolicyNumber") %>' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;    

                                   <asp:ImageButton Height="17" runat = "server"  Width="15" ID = "imgLinked" title="Linked Policy"
                                    OnClick = "imgLinked_OnClick" CommandName = "LinkedPolicy" CausesValidation = "false"
                                    ImageUrl = "~/images/go.gif" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("PolicyNumber") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

Also on itemCommand I have written below line of code.

                if (e.CommandName == "LinkedPolicy")
                {
       PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
                    Button firstButton = (Button)lvActivePolicy.FindControl("imgLinked");
                    trigger.ControlID = firstButton.UniqueID;
                    updActivePolicies.Triggers.Add(trigger);
                    updActivePolicies.Update();
    }   else if (e.CommandName == "Claims")
                {
      PostBackTrigger trigger1 = new PostBackTrigger();
                    Button secondButton = (Button)lvActivePolicy.FindControl("imgClaims");
                    trigger1.ControlID = secondButton.UniqueID;

                    updActivePolicies.Triggers.Add(trigger1);
                    updActivePolicies.Update();
    }
```

COncern Areas:
Once I click on LinkedPolicy Button(imgLinked_OnClick) I get a Popup of Div

```
 AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updActivePolicies, this.GetType(),
                  "Failure", "$('#divLinkPolicies').showModal();", true);
```

I close the Div(PostBack Occurs).

Then again I click Claims button
I get a popup of both Divs i.e  div LinkPolicy and pnlClaims whereas
in server code for imgClaims_Click
I have written below code.

AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updActivePolicies, this.GetType(),
                           "Failure", "$('#pnlClaims').showModal();", true);

I don't know why both the events are firing once I click claims button.
Urgently reply please.
Regards,

Sachin Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

During your closing of your div, an interim solution might be to set the Style attribute to "display", " none", doing this your div will be hidden from your page.

Of course the above solution retains the HTML for said div and a more experienced user could alter the CSS to see the divs.

Comment: Hi Matthew,The page is getting Loaded and the same pop up is opened!I have tried using hideModal. The problem persists.